# SceneKit Fully Stop Simulation from Running at Instant?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, cocoa, scenekit

Trying to get this simple rolling ball simulation running. I cannot seem to find a way to make the ball stop rolling at a said instant, then reset it to the start position with the isResting flag updating just as fast. when running, if the reset button is pressed the ball goes back to the start position but if it is not done rolling it will continue to roll. That is not desired.

```
import Cocoa
import SceneKit

class AppController : NSObject {

@IBOutlet weak var _sceneView: SCNView!

@IBOutlet weak var _pushButton: NSButton!

@IBOutlet weak var _resetButton: NSButton!

private let _radius = 25.0

private let _mySphereNode = SCNNode()


override func awakeFromNib() {

    // assign empty scene
    _sceneView.scene = SCNScene()

    // setup the sphere
    let mySphere = SCNSphere(radius: CGFloat(_radius))
    mySphere.geodesic = true
    mySphere.segmentCount = 50
    mySphere.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents = NSColor.purpleColor().CGColor
    mySphere.firstMaterial!.specular.contents = NSColor.whiteColor().CGColor

    // create node for adding sphere

    _mySphereNode.position = SCNVector3(0.0, CGFloat(_radius), 0.0)
    _mySphereNode.geometry = mySphere

    // add physics
    let spherePhysicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody.dynamicBody()
    spherePhysicsBody.mass = 0.67 // Kg
    spherePhysicsBody.friction = 0.3765
    spherePhysicsBody.rollingFriction = 0.2734
    spherePhysicsBody.damping = 0.5
    _mySphereNode.physicsBody = spherePhysicsBody


    // attach the sphere node to the scene's root node
    _sceneView.scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(_mySphereNode)

    // setup ambient light source
    let ambientLightNode = SCNNode()
    ambientLightNode.light = SCNLight()
    ambientLightNode.light!.type = SCNLightTypeAmbient
    ambientLightNode.light!.color = NSColor(white: 0.35, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
    // add ambient light the scene
    _sceneView.scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(ambientLightNode)

    // setup onmidirectional light
    let omniLightNode = SCNNode()
    omniLightNode.light = SCNLight()
    omniLightNode.light!.type = SCNLightTypeOmni
    omniLightNode.light!.color = NSColor(white: 0.56, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
    omniLightNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0.0, 200.0, 0.0)
    _sceneView.scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(omniLightNode)

    // add plane
    let myPlane = SCNPlane(width: 125.0, height: 2000.0)
    myPlane.widthSegmentCount = 10
    myPlane.heightSegmentCount = 10
    myPlane.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents = NSColor.orangeColor().CGColor
    myPlane.firstMaterial!.specular.contents = NSColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    let planeNode = SCNNode()
    planeNode.geometry = myPlane
    // rotote -90.0 degrees about the y-axis, then rot
    var rotMat = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(-3.14/2.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
    rotMat = SCNMatrix4Rotate(rotMat, -3.14/2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    planeNode.transform = rotMat
    planeNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    // add physcis to plane
    planeNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody.staticBody()
    // add plane to scene
    _sceneView.scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(planeNode)

}

@IBAction func moveBall(sender: AnyObject) {

    if _mySphereNode.physicsBody!.isResting == true {

        let forceApplied = SCNVector3Make(40.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        _mySphereNode.physicsBody!.applyForce(forceApplied, impulse: true)
    }
    else {
        print("Ball not at rest!")
    }

}

@IBAction func resetBall(sender: AnyObject) {

    _mySphereNode.physicsBody!.resetTransform()
}
}
```

Is there a way to stop the SceneKit simulation dead stop and reset to a start position in a way that would force the isResting flag to update to true as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that invalidating the node's geometry and physics body, then reattaching them worked out. Here is the code:

```
import Cocoa
import SceneKit

class AppController : NSObject {

    @IBOutlet weak var _sceneView: SCNView!

    @IBOutlet weak var _pushButton: NSButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var _resetButton: NSButton!

    private let _mySphereNode = SCNNode()

    private func setupScene() {

        // setup ambient light source
        let ambientLightNode = SCNNode()
        ambientLightNode.light = SCNLight()
        ambientLightNode.light!.type = SCNLightTypeAmbient
        ambientLightNode.light!.color = NSColor(white: 0.35, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
        // add ambient light the scene
        _sceneView.scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(ambientLightNode)

        // setup onmidirectional light
        let omniLightNode = SCNNode()
        omniLightNode.light = SCNLight()
        omniLightNode.light!.type = SCNLightTypeOmni
        omniLightNode.light!.color = NSColor(white: 0.56, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
        omniLightNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0.0, 200.0, 0.0)
        _sceneView.scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(omniLightNode)

        // add plane
        let myPlane = SCNPlane(width: 125.0, height: 2000.0)
        myPlane.widthSegmentCount = 10
        myPlane.heightSegmentCount = 10
        myPlane.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents = NSColor.orangeColor().CGColor
        myPlane.firstMaterial!.specular.contents = NSColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        let planeNode = SCNNode()
        planeNode.geometry = myPlane
        // rotote -90.0 degrees about the y-axis, then rot
        var rotMat = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(-3.14/2.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        rotMat = SCNMatrix4Rotate(rotMat, -3.14/2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        planeNode.transform = rotMat
        planeNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        // add physcis to plane
        planeNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody.staticBody()
        // add plane to scene
        _sceneView.scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(planeNode)

    }

    private func setupBall() {

        let _radius = 25.0

        // setup the sphere
        let mySphere = SCNSphere(radius: CGFloat(_radius))
        mySphere.geodesic = true
        mySphere.segmentCount = 50
        mySphere.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents = NSColor.purpleColor().CGColor
        mySphere.firstMaterial!.specular.contents = NSColor.whiteColor().CGColor

        _mySphereNode.position = SCNVector3(0.0, CGFloat(_radius), 0.0)
        _mySphereNode.geometry = mySphere

        // add physics
        let spherePhysicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody.dynamicBody()
        spherePhysicsBody.mass = 0.67 // Kg
        spherePhysicsBody.friction = 0.3765
        spherePhysicsBody.rollingFriction = 0.2734
        spherePhysicsBody.damping = 0.5
        _mySphereNode.physicsBody = spherePhysicsBody
    }

    private func stopBall() {

        _mySphereNode.geometry = nil
        _mySphereNode.physicsBody = nil
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {

        // assign empty scene
        _sceneView.scene = SCNScene()

        // attach the sphere node to the scene's root node
        _sceneView.scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(_mySphereNode)

        setupScene()

        setupBall()
    }

    @IBAction func moveBall(sender: AnyObject) {

        let forceApplied = SCNVector3Make(40.0, 0.0, 0.0)

        if _mySphereNode.physicsBody?.isResting == true {

            _mySphereNode.physicsBody!.applyForce(forceApplied, impulse: true)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func resetBall(sender: AnyObject) {

        // remove the ball from the sphere node
        stopBall()

        // reset the ball
        setupBall()
    }
}
```